# How can only delete the maximum value in a database

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

> Here my code
> i want to delete the highest match_round otherwise show error

```
def destroy(self,match_round):
    match_round = Matchscore.objects.order_by('match_round').first()
    if match_round:
        Matchscore.delete()
        return response("Removed successfully")
    
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Can't delete this round")
```

> matchscore model

```
class Matchscore(TimeStampedModel):
gameevent = models.ForeignKey(GameEvent, null=True, related_name='game_event',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
match_round = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_a = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_one',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
team_a_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_b = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_two',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
team_b_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_won = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Comment: `match_round.delete()`

Comment: actually i tried that but thats not working.

Comment: Does appears an error? Please display (update question with error) if any.

Comment: not error , deletion occurring if any round selected for deleting , i dont want that , only want delete the highest value only

Comment: Can you share `Matchscore` model, please?

Comment: `Matchscore.objects.filter(match_round__isnull=False).order_by('-match_round').first()`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to tell how the data is stored but I'm assuming it is a list.

First I would reorder the list based on match_round (expecting a number), then delete the first item in the list.

```
Matchscore = [
    {"match_round":1},{"match_round":2}
]

#sort
Matchscore = sorted(Matchscore, key = lambda i: i['match_round'],reverse=True)

#delete
del Matchscore[0]

#result
print (Matchscore)
# [{'match_round': 1}]
```

Comment: actually i dont want this logic , my requirement is jst delete the recently added round only,if we deleting round disorederdly show error, not that much complicated, i dont know how to define a delete method in rest django serializer

Comment: Oh, in flask I would define a class for the resource ( `/matchscore` ) then a function under that called delete like `def delete(self):` i think django is similar ...