# Delete function not working in rest django serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

> here is my model serializer
> this delete function not working
> i want to delete the highest value of match_round without any fail
> otherwise show error

> Model serializer
> model

```
class Matchscore(TimeStampedModel):
gameevent = models.ForeignKey(GameEvent, null=True, related_name='game_event',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
match_round = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_a = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_one',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
team_a_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_b = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_two',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
team_b_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_won = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

     
def destroy(self,validated_data):
    gameevent = validated_data.get('gameevent')
    match_round =validated_data.get('match_round')
    match = Matchscore.objects.filter(gameevent=gameevent,match_round=max(match_round))
    if match :
        match.delete()
        return response("success")
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Can't delete this round")
```

Comment: Please share your error.

Comment: not error , actually default delete function of modelviewset working, my customised deletion not working . i want to delete only max valued data, but now  i can delete any data by inbuild deletee method of django serilaizer

Comment: You said its not working, but what is not working ? What kind of data is there on match_round ? Can you please share reproductible code (inputs) ?

Comment: Is this fucntion `destroy` in your `ModelSerializer`? As far i know, ModelSerializer does not has `def destory`. Maybe you custom ModeSerializer, please share user your ViewSet and Serializer more complete.

Comment: i will share the model

Comment: modelserializer has delete function?

Comment: i want to override the inbuild delete and method and want to apply  customisation in model serializer, cant i use destroy in model serializer?

Comment: `Matchscore.objects.filter(match_round__isnull=False).order_by('-match_round').first()`

Comment: How about above?

Comment: I have check yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71168981/how-can-only-delete-the-maximum-value-in-a-database..
I just know, your queryset is not correctly to get highest value. My bad.

Comment: Dont forget to filter `gameevent`. So:
`Matchscore.objects.filter(gameevent=gameevent, match_round__isnull=False).order_by('-match_round').first()`

Comment: need of  order_by().first() ?

Comment: Yes, order_by `match_round` descending, then get the first.